# Check Chart Area empty

Tags: vb.net, charts

I am developing a Windows form application to plot a chart. Depending on the availability of data, the chart will be plotted.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles generatePlot.Click
        ClearChart() 'Clear existing chart series

        Try
            'Doing a very long process here to plot the chart

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ErrorToString)
            Exit Sub
        End Try            

        'Save chart as an image
        Chart1.SaveImage(specDataHelper.imageSave, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)   

End Sub
```

On the above function, if the chart area is not empty, I would like to save it as an image. Else, I wanted to skip the saving as an image part.

How do I check if the chart area is not empty? I'm not sure which property to look into.

Comment: When fetching the data, create a variable that holds information whether there was any data or not and use it as a condition for the save.

Comment: @Esko. Good catch. I had resulted in checking for the points in my series whether it's empty or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good suggestion from @Esko. I resulted to checking the series whether it is empty or not:

```
'Save chart as an image
        If (Me.Chart1.Series("Result").Points.Count <> 0) Then
            Chart1.SaveImage(specDataHelper.imageSave, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
        End If
```

And, working perfectly..